# input a multi digit number into a textbox and get a solution automatically without using a button

Tags: c#, sql

I have been trying to create an automatic solution for my project where in when I input a number the corresponding data is displayed in a read-only textBox. This idea works great with a button as the input is a multi digit, the moment I input the first number the code calls the else function.

sample dB

```
b_id                 b_name
1                     Huston
15                    Berlin
06                    Rio
```

here when i enter the first b_id the output is Huston.
the second one automatically calls Huston and third before i can enter the 2nd digit the code yells the else statement.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        .........c#....

        SqlDataReader reader;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select b_id,b_name from branches where b_id=@b_id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b_id", textBox1.Text);

        
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                label2.Text = reader["b_name"].ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No data was found in this ID");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a debouncer. Instead to start search immediately on each text change, reset a timer, that is initialized to 750ms. Then add your lookup code into the timer elapsed event. So whenever something is entered there is a delay of 3/4 second, before search is started and the result or error message is shown. Also, to improve usage, show the error message in the label and not in a message box.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write your `if-else` like below :

```
if(reader.Read())
    label2.Text = reader["b_name"].ToString();
else
    label2.Text = "No data found!";
```

Hitting the database each time you type a char in the textbox is not a good idea. A better approach could be what @Oliver suggested or if the table `branches` is not so big, load all the data into a datatable and search in it from your textchange event.

Comment: i used the async function for the timer. but as soon as the timer runs out the systems yells out the else function and then displays the data. Since my form is a bit complex having the label display a large portion on screen will interfere with the rest of the form.

Comment: I would suggest you to post a new question with the issue you are having in timer async function. Just you need to post your code and specify the exact issue!